# More elegant way to achieve dependent parallel tasks with waitUntil with declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While I'm able to achieve the result that I need which is having parallel stages that will wait for the previous ( or any given ) stage to be completed before proceeding. I feel this isn't the correct way to achieve the desired end state. But even after a few researches on github and stackoverflow, i could not find a proper answer or lead on how I could achieve dependent parallel stages within declarative pipelines.

```
def action_a_status
def action_b_status
def action_c_status
def action_d_status

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Deploy") {
            parallel {
                stage("action 1") {
                    steps {
                        sleep 10
                        script {
                            action_a_status="completed"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("action 2") {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            waitUntil {
                              action_a_status=="completed"
                            }
                            sleep 5
                            action_b_status="completed"    
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("action 3") {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            waitUntil {
                              action_b_status=="completed"
                            }
                            sleep 3
                            action_c_status="completed"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("action 4") {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            waitUntil {
                              action_c_status=="completed"
                            }
                            action_c_status="completed"
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a demonstration, please check this gif:
[image: demo]

Comment: Im not sure about the background but why to you use parallel if the actions can not be executed paralelly?

Comment: Hi @SergejLopatkin the context would be exclusively on the "grouping" organization, we have a quite extensive pipeline that the visual representation would greatly extend horizontaly, so the idea would be , instead of having multiple steps  we could create dependent parallel stages that will only start when the parent stage finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its important to notice that this isnt the best approach to achieve the desired result, and i dnt found one proper aproach to group stages, so  I opted to not proceed with non intuitive code in order to improve BlueOcean visualization of pipelines. Instead, ill be just using steps.

Keep safe everyone and code clean.